# Difference between dispatcher and context switcher?

Tags: operating-system, scheduling

I am studying OS now. I know context switcher is responsible for switch the process for CPU to run. It also save and restore the state of a process so that the execution can be resumed at a later time. But, I am not quiet understand dispatcher.. What does it responsible for?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As already stated in the other answer, the actual meaning depends on the context in which these terms are used.

---

When an interrupt occurs the CPU hands control to system level code. This code is responsible for saving the context of the interrupted task, establishing a context to run system level code and restoring the context of a (possibly different) interrupted task. That's what I'd call *context switcher*.

The term *dispatching* is associated with scheduling and means roughly selecting the next task to run.

So in a typical task switch, for example due to a timer interrupt, the context switcher first saves the context of the interrupted task, establishes the context to run system code and then calls the dispatcher. Its job is to select a task to switch into. That task is returned to the context switcher, which restores the associated context.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that there tends to be formal definitions of such terms and usage can vary among systems. That said, what you are calling a "context switcher" is normally called a "dispatcher". They are the same.

Answer (score 0):

So yes, context switching refers to saving the context of the current running process so that it can be resumed later and loading the values of the registers and program counter with the context of the coming process.

So what is dispatching?

Short-term schedulers decide which process of all present in the ready queue should be allocated the CPU next. So short-term schedulers select the process which is to be executed on CPU and calls the dispatcher. Then **dispatcher performs the context switching** and saves the context of the currently running process, removes it from running state and dispatches the process selected by the short-term scheduler to the CPU.
As a conclusion, dispatching is a process which involves a context switch, though context switch needn't be called by the dispatcher only. Context switching can also occur due to interrupts.